# JpaBaseConfiguration exclusion auto-configuration issue spring-boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

We have spring boot application, and as part of it we exclude certain classes for some technical reasons.

This works fine on spring boot version 1.4.3.RELEASE. Now we need to move to spring boot version 1.5.9.RELEASE. Now we are getting below error:

```
rror starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
[2018-03-27 10:17:38,773] RequestID: @ ERROR[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'](org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication:771) - Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [com.citi.icg.as.postings.config.DemoApplicationConfig]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: The following classes could not 
be excluded because they are not auto-configuration classes:
        - org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration

        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processDeferredImportSelectors(ConfigurationClassParser.java:482)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:184)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:308)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:228)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:270)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:93)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:686)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:524)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
        at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:134)
        at org.springframework.boot.legacy.context.web.SpringBootContextLoaderListener.initWebApplicationContext(SpringBootContextLoaderListener.java:61)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:481)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:181)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1871)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3173)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1529)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:488)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
```

Code which worked 1.4.3 failing with 1.5.9:

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource("classpath:applicationContext.xml")
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {
    JpaBaseConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class, FreeMarkerAutoConfiguration.class, DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
    DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class
})
@ConditionalOnWebApplication
@EnableRestfulServices
public class DemoApplicationConfig {
```

Comment: Just remove DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class from auto configuration as far as database configuration is concerned. Let me know if its working fine

Comment: can you share the pom.xml for the project?

Comment: @kakabali in pom.xml only parent is spring boot starter parent and rest nothing much

Comment: @Afridi how is it connected ?

Comment: We also needed to remove datasource autoconfiguration in order to add some custom Oracle properties. Be sure to provide @Beans for the items you normally get from autoconfiguration. Also, if using Tomcat DBCP, be sure to update the connection pool properties/yml to include the spring.datsource.tomcat.* properties if you're not doing this already.

Comment: @MichaelPeacock we create our own beans using our own PropertyResource, so removing it in 1.5.9 wont cause any issues right